# How can i create code generator in eclipse that can generate code regarding the class atributes

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit

I am a automation test developer, I use selenium + page object model + Junit for doing my tests. Which leads me to a problem, in every single test class I declare attributes like these:

```
By miscellaneousContainerFinder = By.cssSelector(".MISCELLANEOUS_ROW");
By goodbyeTextContainerFinder = By.cssSelector(".GOOD_BYE_TEXT_ROW");
By driversBarriersContainerFinder = By.cssSelector(".DRIVERS_BARRIERS_ROW");
```

But much more attributes, 15-20 of these. What gives me a headache is that I need to create for each of these "By's" simple methods, such as:

```
    public String getEmailComment() {

        try {
            return descriptionTabContainer.findElement(emailCommentFinder).getText();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

or methods that clicks, or types in a WebElement. So I thought about the way eclipse can generate getters/setters for the attributes, I know that I can edit the way these codes are generated, and insert any code that I'd like. But how can I add new methods specifying also the name they will have and the return?

I'd like to have the option to generate methods like these - generate getter/setter, generate clickMethod, generate sendKeys method, generate getText method.

Is this possible or am I dreaming?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these attributes and methods the same for every test class ? Could you consider puting them as constants and static methods on a common class ?
You could then add `import static ThatHelperClass.*;` in your test file and use the constantes/meethods

Comment: Unfortunately they are not the same. And I need my methods to have a significant name, so when you are reading the test, you know what it does easily.

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question, something similar happens to me a lot and it's about time I do something about it.

Here is how to do it with Templates:
Go to Window>Preferences>Editor>Templates

and create this template:

```
private By ${word_selection}Finder = By.cssSelector("");//TODO add selector

public String get${word_selection}(){
    try {
            return descriptionTabContainer.findElement(${word_selection}Finder).getText();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now if you write some variable, mark it and click ctrl+space select your template name, you get your code.

Comment: Humm, that's a good solution actually =)

I was hoping for something that I could declare all my BYs and then generate the code for all of them. But probably it would take a lot more work than the solution that you provided, which solves 80% of my problem! Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate code automatically for each locator:

https://github.com/naukri-engineering/SeleniumCodeGenerator

Features:

It helps to reduce/nullify repetitive coding effort in building page objects and writing automation code for field level validations.

• Easy to integrate(just need java and ant)

• Can be run on windows, Linux and Mac OS • Generates Clean Code and eliminates typos

```
This Can be enhanced/used for Selenium, Appium and Robotium etc
```